# Unable to resolve ignoreResourceNotFound = true in @PropertySource. Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

Getting method not found Exception. In eclipse no error but when i compile in maven getting error. 
Using Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE.

What am i missing ? In eclipse no error.

```
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile


Compilation failure
/home/jinto/workspace/gb_New_V2.0/maven.1390211538509/greatbuyz-ussd/src/main/java/com/onmobile/gb/ussd/UssdProperties.java:[20,60] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method ignoreResourceNotFound()
  location: @interface org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

---

```
Code: 

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:ussd.properties",
            "file:${user.home}/.gb/ussd.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
    @Component
    public class UssdProperties implements InitializingBean {

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }

        @Value("${ussdScreenConfigFilePath:null}")
        public String ussdScreenConfigFilePath;
    ...
    }
```

Comment: check your dependencies. Do a `mvn: dependency:tree` and check the spring versions. I guess there is a conflicting spring jar on your classpath.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. The problem was one of the dependency was internally depending on older spring version.